# Is it possible to create map files for a 3D game using AutoCAD and 3ds Max?

Tags: unity, 3d-modeling, asset-workflow

Is it possible to make maps for games using AutoCAD and 3ds Max?

I am studying architecture and I am making pretty good making 3D objects. I would like to make them for games, but I don't know what program I can use.

Is it possible to export something from CAD or 3ds to some game engine like Unity?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. I recommend reading the guide on [asking good questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); as mentioned in the answer you received, some basic searching would have covered the basics. The guidance on down voting includes "... does not show any research effort ...". If you've done some research, then summarizing the steps you took & focusing on remaining problems is usually enough to avoid down votes.

Answer (score 2):

"Is it possible" is a question you can answer for yourself.

[Searching "Unity model file formats"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity%20model%20file%20formats&ia=web) takes you to [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/3D-formats.html) and [this one](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html) which confirm that you can use models in the following formats in Unity:

- .fbx
- .dae (Collada)
- .dxf
- .obj
- .max (Autodesk® 3ds Max®)
- .blend (Blender)

So that already answers the 3ds Max part of your question. The only remaining question is whether AutoCAD can export one of these formats that Unity can import.

So our next search is ["AutoCAD export formats"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=autocad%20export%20formats&ia=web) or just ["AutoCAD file formats"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=autocad%20file%20formats&ia=web). This lists .dxf as a possible save format, which matches Unity's import list.

Now let's see if there's any published advice about using the programs together in this way, by [searching "AutoCAD export to Unity"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=autocad%20export%20to%20unity&ia=web).

That turns up [this existing Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483194/3064164), strongly advising to *not* use AutoCAD for this purpose, for reasons explained in some detail there.

Software recommendations are not on-topic for this exchange, so we can't tell you what software to use. What I wanted to do with this answer was demonstrate how you can find this information on your own. [Searching "making models for Unity"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=making%20models%20for%20unity&ia=web) will turn up tons of guides and tutorials you can peruse to get a sense of the workflow in various content creation tools, and decide which one you want to try.

Since Unity is free to install, you can even do a quick test, importing some model file you have lying around, to see if you run into any snags in the process or encounter any unwanted effects - that helps you ask a more focused question about how to deal with that specific obstacle.

Skipping this step of searching/testing for yourself can make your question appear to "not show research effort", which is one reason why questions might get down-voted. Doing this legwork will help you get the information you need, and ask high-quality questions that attract upvotes and detailed answers instead.